# swashbucle aspnet.core groupname

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I want to group controller operations.
At controller level added

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName ="Test")]
```

On the SwaggerGen options added

```
c.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));
c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
```

This worked fine

I then introduced versioning.
On the SwaggerGen options added

```
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider()
               .GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
{
    c.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName,
        new Info()
        {
            Title = $"{description.ApiVersion}",
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
            Description = "Developer Guide",
        });
}
```

Now the it fails to load the definition. if I only add

```
c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
```

Then it groups the actions via the version number.
I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1 and .NET Core 2.1

Any ideas/help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, so a bit more playing and I think I've resolved by adding

```
c.TagActionsBy(api => new[] { "Test" });
```

within each api version group within SwaggerGen

Thanks if anyone was looking and sorry for wasting anyone's time

Comment: OK, so this didn't work is we have more than one controller so the question is still open, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same problem you're having and resolved it utilizing the following ...

```
options.TagActionsBy(api =>
{
    string tag;
    if (api.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
    {
        var attribute = descriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        tag = attribute?.GroupName ?? descriptor.ControllerName;
    }
    else
    {
        tag = api.GroupName;
    }

    var tags = new List<string>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
    {
        tags.Add(tag);
    }
    return tags;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete code, but it shows the gist of what you need to do.  Create a list of version info builder, and then apply that in swagger config

```
var versionSupportResolver = new Func<ApiDescription, string, bool>((apiDescription, version) =>
{
    var path = apiDescription.RelativePath.Split('/');
    var pathVersion = path[1];
    return string.Equals(pathVersion, version, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
});

var versionInfoBuilder = new Action<VersionInfoBuilder>(info => {
    info.Version("v2", "My API v2");
    info.Version("v1", "My API v1");
});

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        /// ...
        /// ...
        c.MultipleApiVersions(versionSupportResolver, versionInfoBuilder);
        /// ...
        /// ...
    });
```